# Athena cast string representation of dateand time into timestamp or date type

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

**Input:** I have a `date` column and i want to cast that column into either `timestamp` or `date` datatypes.

**Example:**
`2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000` (String Data type)  ==>  `2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000` (Date or Timestamp Data type)

**Can anyone suggest solution for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For timestamp use below query by replacing the actual value with the column name :

```
select date_parse('2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f') as time;
```

above query will give you

```
time
1   2020-09-07 05:12:25.247
```

If you want date then cast above timestamp as date :

```
select cast(date_parse('2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f') as date) as day
```

will give you

```
day
1   2020-09-07
```

verify the types using typeof operator:

```
select typeof(date_parse('2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')). --> timestamp

select typeof(cast(date_parse('2020-09-07 05:12:25.247000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f') as date)). ->> date
```